# C# strudel sign

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, keyword

While coding in C#, I by mistake added a strudel sign before a variable in if statement (instead of exclamation mark).

```
bool b = false;
if (@b)
{

}
```

I surprised it compiled successfully without any error.

I wonder: What is the meaning of the above code?

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strudel - "Strudel had been part of Israeli cuisine since the arrival of numerous immigrants from Central Europe in the 1920s and 1930s, and the name has been taken into Hebrew (שטרודל).
Since the introduction of email, the at sign (@) became known as "strudel" in colloquial Hebrew."

Comment: I suppose they call it that because Snails are not kosher.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@` can be used to "escape" identifiers, in case you want to use keywords. For example:

```
int @class = 10;
```

Of course it's usually a bad idea to use keywords as identifiers, but if you're using a class library which happens to use them, it can be hard to avoid. It can also be useful sometimes to use "@this" for situations where you want to *effectively* have a `this` reference, but for whatever reason you can't use one. (These are pretty few and far between, but I've seen it a couple of times, and it's worth at least knowing about.)

Comment: Very impressive, Skeet, but what do you know about strudel? Hmm? :D

Answer (score 11):

Jon's answer sums it up. An example of when you must use this technique of escaping is specifying HTML attributes in anonymous types to helper methods in ASP.NET MVC.

```
Html.ActionLink("text", "action", "controller",
    new { @class = "some-css-class" }, null);
```

I've also hit this when composing anonymous types for posting via HTTP using JSON encoding, where you cannot modify the remote API.

+1 for 'strudel' too :)